# Makefile clean target and .PHONY

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wrote this Makefile with a PHONY target that loops over a set of subdirectories and executes $(MAKE)

```
SUBDIRS:= dir_1 dir_2 dir_3 dir_n

libs:$(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@;

.PHONY: libs  $(SUBDIRS)
```

I have tried with this code but it doesn't work.

```
SUBDIRS:=dir_1 dir_2 dir_3 dir_n
CLEANDIRS:=dir_1 dir_2 dir_3 dir_n

libs:$(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@;

clean:$(CLEANDIRS)
$(CLEANDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ clean;

.PHONY: libs  $(SUBDIRS)
.PHONY: clean  $(CLEANDIRS)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: There are no loops here at all. What is the problem you are having exactly?

Comment: I guess that with the addition of the clean rule make becomes unable to distinguish between libs and clean

Comment: Ah. Yes, you are specifying two different recipes for the same target. That should have make yell at you about a redefinition and that it is ignoring the older commands (would have been useful to put that in your post). Yes, you can't do what you are trying to do here like this. You can manually loop over the value of `$(SUBDIRS)` in the body of the `libs` and `clean` `.PHONY` targets though if you wanted to.